# Cat Execve NASM

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, system-calls, execve

I am trying to output a file in Assembly using `cat` with the `execve` syscall, but I am having a bit of trouble and I don't know why.

```
section .text
global  _start

_start:
    mov  al,  59  ; Syscall number
    xor  rdx, rdx ; No enviornment variables
    push rdx

    ; Add arg1
    mov  rdi, "/bin/cat"
    push rdi
    mov  rdi, rsp
    push rdx

    ; Add arg2
    mov  si,  "xt"
    push rsi
    mov  rsi, "//file.t"
    push rsi
    mov  rsi, rsp

    ; Call execve
    syscall
```

I checked to make sure `/file.txt` exists. Then looked at the stack with GDB before the syscall is done, and everything also looks correct:

```
0x00007fffc25f8628│+0x0000: "//file.txt"         ← $rsp, $rsi
0x00007fffc25f8630│+0x0008: 0x0000000000007478 ("xt"?)
0x00007fffc25f8638│+0x0010: 0x0000000000000000
0x00007fffc25f8640│+0x0018: "/bin/cat"   ← $rdi
```

How can I call `execve` correctly?

Comment: You need the arguments as an array of pointers.

Comment: As Jester said for arg2, but also that array needs three values, the first is the name of the program which could be `cat` or `/bin/cat` as you see fit. The third element in that array needs to be a NULL pointer. Finally, `execve()` itself needs a third argument for the environment in rdx, but this can just be a NULL pointer.

Comment: I will try making an array of pointers instead. Also the third argument is set in rdx at the beginning where `xor` is used to zero it.

Comment: Your code is assuming that registers start out zeroed.  That's true in `_start` in a static executable, but not in actual shellcode which it looks like you're trying to create.  You need `xor eax, eax` first.  Or `push 59` / `pop rax`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an 64-bit example, written in nasm, that runs an external command with arguments and this works for me.

```
; ---------------------------------------------------------
; Executes external command 
; ---------------------------------------------------------

SECTION .data

    ; Important: The strings must be null-terminated
    bin   db '/usr/bin/nano',0x0
    arg1  db '-w', 0x0
    arg2  db '/etc/fstab', 0x0

    args  dq arg1, arg2, 0x0

SECTION .text
global _start
_start:

    ; Invoke SYS_EXECVE
    mov rax, 59
    mov rdi, bin
    mov rsi, args
    xor rdx, rdx                    ; envp[] is not used
    syscall

    ; Quit
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

Best regards.

Comment: That's not shellcode.  It looks like the OP was trying to create shellcode which could hypothetically be injected in a buffer overflow (into a write+exec page).  That means: position-independent, no separate sections, and no `0` bytes.  That's why the code in the question is doing stuff like `mov  rsi, "//file.t"` (with the redundant `//` to pad to a width of 8 bytes, because the immediate has to be 64-bit, or 32-bit sign extended.  Or zero extended if you did `mov eax, ...`)

Comment: [How to pass argv arguments to execv in asm on 64-bit (linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56047512) is a non-shellcode Q&A where this would be a good answer, except that it already has an answer like but also explaining the API for `execve` and thus why an array of pointers-to-strings is needed.  [What is proper way to call execve with arguments in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52171273) is a 32-bit version with a shellcode version.